# Cohomology of higher codimensional arrangements

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, hyperplane-arrangements

[Hyperplane arrangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_hyperplanes) are classical objects of study and there is a large literature on this subject, e.g. dealing with computing the cohomology of the complement. I am looking for similar results about higher-codimensional arrangements, which I have been struggling to find. For example, suppose $\mathcal{A} = \{ V_1, \dots, V_k \}$ is a set of linear subspaces of $W = \mathbb{R}^n$ (or $W = \mathbb{C}^n$ if it helps) of varying dimensions, not necessarily all the same. What are general concrete results about e.g. the cohomology ring of $W \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^k V_i$?

(By "concrete", I mean something useful for computations, not an existence result or something theoretically correct but impossible to handle in practice. For example, I know that I can take the Leray spectral sequence of the inclusion $\bigcup_{i=1}^k V_i \subset W$ and try to go on from there, but getting from $E^2$ to $H^*$ is very nontrivial.)

Comment: The paper by De Concini and Procesi on wonderful models allows for the computation of the cohomology for general subspace arrangements. See section 5.3

Comment: I remember Fred Cohen giving lectures on homotopy type of such arrangements, but as many Cohen results they probably were never published.

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/LA-BIBLIO/trunk/Bjorner/Bjornersubspacearrangements.pdf